# Колонки по типу фреймов на css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Пытаюсь создать три колонки каждая должна проматываться отдельно, по типу того как это устроено в верстке на фреймах.
Я использовал Bootstrap

У меня получилось это сделать только ограничивая высоту дива, а мне надо растянуть див на всю высоту страницы.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    <div class="scrollspy-example">
        Много текста
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    <div class="scrollspy-example">
        Много текста
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    <div class="scrollspy-example">
        Много текста
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.scrollspy-example {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Вот пример того что выходит https://jsfiddle.net/5rexp6sc/

Как, в общем, сделать три колонки на всю высоту страницы чтобы текст в каждой проматывался по вертикали отдельно?

Спасибо за любую помощ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А я бы сделал вот как-то так:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
body {
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    background: #99582A;
    color: #fff;
}
.row {
    font-size: 0;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
.col {
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
</div>
<div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
</div>
<div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sequi perferendis ab iure vel nobis tenetur illo similique repudiandae! Nihil, tempora in odit esse sequi ad recusandae incidunt atque expedita.
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы делал это с помощью Java-script:

Берем высоту окна браузера, отнимаем от нее всё лишнее, ставим эту высоту для колонок. Пример для jQuery:

> $('.scrollspy-example').height($(window).height()-10);

10 -- в данном случае отступ, который у вас в `margin-top`

Comment: Хочется реализацию на css, но спасибо и за это. :)

Comment: Тут штука в том, что у `height` при выражении в процентах есть нюансы, которые зависят от контекста. И еще сюрпризы в экзотических браузерах.
Вот, например, статья: https://learn.javascript.ru/height-percent